# Libxml cross compile for embedded system

Tags: c, cross-platform, libxml2, xml-libxml

I am trying to figure how to compile libxml2 library for my embedded system, which is powerpc architecture and has no os (bare metal). It seems like I need to execute configure file and set CC flag to something I do not know what. Thanks for help!

Comment: it is not necessary to set CC variable just passing the host variable value is enough

Comment: So should it be like "./configure --host=powerpc-unknown-none'? Don't I need to specify the embedded executable compiler on CC flag?

Comment: it is not necessary but no wrong in mentioning it either

Answer (score 0):

CC is the executable of your C compiler.  It could be something like powerpc-linux-gcc, but really that really depends on your cross compilation environment.

Comment: So if I would like to compile on my PowerPc-Bare Metal, I need to specify the executable compiler at CC flag? In addition, There is a flag called Host, which specifies the target machine. What about it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The "host" is there you build and the "target" is where you run.

Comment: There is no "target" option, only "build" and "host".

Comment: Well, it's kind of hard to continue and help without more docs or the hardware and toolchain.